# Can't write to txt file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am trying to write to a `.txt` file within a program, and I am using the following code snippet. I want to output a line of the form:

`a(space)b`

but I get nothing on the txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string a = "string";
    int b = 0;

    fstream f;
    f.open("filename.txt",ios::in | ios::out );
    f << a << ' ' << b << endl;
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might taking loot at another file filename.txt.

Comment: If the file does not exist, and you try to open it for reading (`ios::in`), it should [fail](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open). Have you tried opening the file just for writing (`ios::out`)?

Comment: Probably you also want to `#include <string>` instead of the C one. This doesn't event compile under Visual Studio.

Comment: @rturrado but the file already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you try this piece of code:

```
f.open("filename.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
if (!f.is_open()) {
    cout << "error";
}
```

you will see that the file is never opened. `ios::in` requires an already existing file ([`std::fstream::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)):

[image]

---

It should work if you should only pass `std::ios::out` to `f.open()`:

```
f.open("filename.txt", ios::out);
```

---

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you shouldn't be `using namespace std;`.

Comment: but the file already exists at the time I am compiling

Comment: pass `std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out` to overwrite and write to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version. Few changes:

1. Include the correct header `<string>` instead of `<cstring>`
2. No `using namespace std;`
3. Use `std::ofstream` for output
4. No `.open()`: pass the filename in the constructor
5. Check if the file is valid after opening
6. No `.close()`. Let the destructor do its job.
7. No `std::endl` if `'\n'` is enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string a = "string";
    int b = 0;

    std::ofstream f("filename.txt");
    if (!f) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f << a << ' ' << b << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```